# why is the numpy array used to create the image different from the array obtained when I convert the image back to array in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy

I created an image in numpy using my own input arrays of rgb values. When I converted the image back to the arrays in numpy, the rgb values in the arrays were different from the rgb values I created the image with.

```
d = np.zeros([400,200,3],dtype='uint8')
d[:200,:100] = [190,0,0]#the fist 100 rows of the first 200 arrays will contain color a
d[:200,100:] = [0,0,190]# the last 100 rows of the first 200 arrays will contain color b
d[200:,:100] = [0,190,0]# the first 100 rows of the last 200 arrays will contain color c
d[200:,100:] = [255,255,0]# the last 100 rows of the last 200 arrays will contain color d
```

When I convert the image back to array, array value[ 190,0,0] used to create the image becomes value[190,0,2] and value[0,0,190] becomes value[1,0,190]. I also noticed that the pixels at the edges between two adjacent colors pick completely different array values and I don't know where they came from

can someone please explain why that is the case? Is it because of the extension of the image I choose to use or because ? Thanks

Comment: you need to post your code and an example of your current and expected output, as "different" can be the difference between off by a small number due to a lossy compression or your code not doing what you think it does.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75902839/edit) your question to add those things.

Comment: yes, saving images as jpeg is a lossy conversion that changes the image, you should use png instead. that's your answer.